# How many permutations are possible with these digits?

Tags: combinatorics

A question I'm struggling with is the following:

- How many different numbers can you make with the following digits (presuming
  numbers starting with zeros are allowed): $1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0$?

I'd say the answer is: $\frac{8!}{2!3!2!}=1680$

I came up with this answer by figuring there are $8!$ different numbers possible if every number is unique, but since that's not the case we have to divide by the number of permutations of the recurring numbers. I.e., we can arrange $2$ and $2$ in $2!$ ways, $3$, $3$ and $3$ in $3!$ ways and $0$ and $0$ in $2!$ ways. That gives us $\frac{8!}{2!3!2!}$.

However, I'm not sure if that's correct

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @amWhy, I'm not looking for numbers with 8 distinct digits. I can only use the digits I posted once. So you're saying my answer presumes I can use every mentioned digit as much as I want (including numbers like 2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2)? How should I approach this question then?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.  An additional way to view this is by selecting which of the spaces are occupied by 0's and which are occupied by 'not0s', there are $\binom{8}{2}$ number of ways, then figure out from the spaces remaining which of them are occupied by 1's and 'not1or0s', $\binom{6}{1}$ number of ways.  Then find from the spaces remaining the spaces occupied by the 2's and 'not2or1or0s', $\binom{5}{2}$ number of ways.  Finally from the spaces remaining find the spaces occupied by the 3's and 'not3or2or1or0's: $\binom{3}{3}$ number of ways.

$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{3} = \frac{8!6!5!3!}{2!6!1!5!2!3!3!0!} = \frac{8!}{2!1!2!3!}$

Thinking of it in the manner mentioned above and generalizing to the arbitrary case justifies the formula $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!\cdots n_k!}$ for arbitrary number of elements and arbitrary number of repetitions of each.